# AMS: interact with external process

Tags: flash, adobe, flash-media-server

Adobe Media Server 5.0.3 on CentOS 6.3

1. Is it possible to interact with another running process on the same server out of serverside actionscript?
2. How?
3. If there is more than 1 option, what are the (dis)advantages to them?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

No out of box way, but you can call http link of local php server, that would execute shell/bash command for you.